# Can Android Studio apk run in apple phone?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, android-studio

I am trying to developing a simple app using JAVA for my school project. I am using android studio to develop my application, which I learned android studio in school. But i want to run my app in both android and apple phone. So here is my question, is it possible for my android studio app to run in apple phone, and if not, what should i do so that it can run in both android and apple phone?

Comment: if you have any mac-book then follow this https://kobiton.com/topics/develop-deploy-and-test-flutter-apps/

Comment: .apk file is only for android, if you want to develop iOS platform you can go for any hybrid app development. check-> https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use android apk into iOS. 
I suggest you to go with some kind of Hybrid applications, like Flutter(Google's one), ReactNative(Facebook's one). In this you can develop applications and final build can install in both Android and iOS.

If you still need any help [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs) or [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

Answer (score 0):

You can but it's not that straightforward. You can use Android studio to make a [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) project and then deploy it to iOS. But you need to learn Dart and Flutter's conceptions and whole developing processes, maybe it's not as easy as you imagined.

Comment: Can i know how to deploy the flutter project into IOS devices? Can i just connect the Apple phone to android studio(with flutter) and run it? If not, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Android apk cannot run on ios because of different platforms,the best option is to use cross-platforms tools in mobile application development i recommend [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs)

Comment: Can i know how to deploy the flutter project into IOS devices? Can i just connect the Apple phone to android studio(with flutter) and run it? If not, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Flutter project on iOS Device. You need to Open the default Xcode workspace in your project by running open ios/Runner.xcworkspace in a terminal window from your Flutter project directory in macOS.